# ConcurrentHashMap.clear() What will happen to read threads?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

We were maintaining the cache using ConcurrentHashMap 
Often times the cache needs to be refreshed What is the bestway to refresh the cache?

1.Update the cache , Remove all stale keys.

2.Clear the cache and insert fresh keys again from the content.

Case 1: all read threads will not be blocked, once updated they will get the updated value.

Case 2: Here my question what will happen to read threads when we will clear the cache?Do they get null value ?

What is the best strategy to update the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most reliable answer as usual is in API, which for this situation says *... For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries...*

Comment: So following strategy 1 i.e update all cache and remove stale keys is much better than strategy 2 right?

Comment: I would choose strategy 1 otherwise reading threads will be getting nulls while you are filling the map.

Comment: How about wrapping the call to invoke with `clear` with  `synchronized`